# Is it possible to pass a value while inserting?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trigger like this:

```
IF ( value > new.value ) THEN

    ...

END IF
```

It will be executed `AFTER INSERT`. I need to pass `value` (it is a number) while inserting because of using it into the condition of the trigger. Any idea how can I pass it?

Noted that, currently it is hardcoded into trigger like `IF ( 5 > new.value ) THEN`. And all I'm trying to do is passing that `5` dynamically while inserting.

Comment: This need doesn't make sense.  If you need to do something regarding an external value, then you can do it independently of the trigger.

Comment: As far as I know, triggers only have the NEW and/or OLD values of the record they are processing; you could have the trigger query some sort of settings table, or maybe use a session variable (they are global to the connection); but neither is what I would call a good idea. (i.e. last resort, can't fix, or not allowed to fix the "problem" in a better way.) As Gordon said, if the calculations/handling is dependent on an external value, that should probably be handled before it reaches the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no defined mechanism for passing an argument to a TRIGGER.

The only things I can think of is a user-defined variable (but I wouldn't really want to go there), or a `SELECT` statement to retrieve the value from a table.

---

We can set a user-defined variable in our session:

```
SET @value_for_after_insert_trigger = 5 ;
```

Then perform an INSERT

```
INSERT INTO mytable (...) VALUES (...)
```

when the AFTER INSERT trigger is fired (for each row), the trigger body can reference a user-defined variable. For example:

```
   DECLARE ln_value INTEGER;
   SET ln_value = @value_for_after_insert_trigger;
```

Then we can do

```
   IF ( ln_value > NEW.value ) THEN
```

Note that we aren't guaranteed that some other statement in our session won't modify our user-defined variable. For example, a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger might execute a statement such as:

```
  SET @value_for_after_insert_trigger = 42 ;
```

... overwriting the value that was previously stored. The `AFTER INSERT` trigger would read the currently assigned value, getting the 42, not the 5 we specified earlier. And we aren't guaranteed that the `AFTER INSERT` trigger won't perform some action that modifies the value.

```
  SET @value_for_after_insert_trigger = @value_for_after_insert_trigger + 1;
```

affecting the trigger execution for subsequent rows.

---

I do *not* advocate this as a design. I would avoid using user-defined variables like this.

---

Another alternative would be to use a `SELECT` statement to query the value from a table.

Comment: I had thought about your two approaches before asking, but still they are hardcode. thank you anyway, upvote